# La propiedad [file] no existe en esta instancia de colección. Laravel

Tags: laravel

estoy usando por primera vez Laravel en un proyecto en el cual estoy trabajando, y tengo un problema; estoy intentando traer algunos datos al index.blade, pero me sale el siguiente error Property [file] does not exist on this collection instance. Estoy recorriendo con un foreach la variable img

```
<div class="card-body">
          @foreach ($img as $post)
              <div class="tab-content">
                  <div class="active tab-pane" id="activity">
                      <div class="post">
                          <div class="row mb-3">
                              <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
                                  <a href="images/{{$post->file }}" class="fancybox" rel="ligthbox">
                                      <img src="images/{{$post->file }}" class="zoom img-fluid">
                                  </a>
                              </div>                      
                          </div>

                          <div>
                            {{$post->description}}
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          @endforeach
        </div>
```

La cual fue declarada en el la function index del controlador

```
$img = Image::with('post')->orderBy('id','desc')->get()->groupBy('post_id');
    return view('perfil.index', compact('img'));
```

Aqui las migraciones

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('description')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

public function up()
{
    Schema::create('images', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('file');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->bigInteger('post_id')->unsigned()->index(); 
        $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');

        $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned()->index(); 
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
    });
}
```

Y los modelos, entre las cuales existe una relación de uno a muchos

```
class Image extends Model{
public function post()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
}
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(user::class);
}}

class Post extends Model{
public function Image()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Image::class);
}
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}}
```

Alguna idea del por que el error?

Comment: El error es muy claro, habría que ver la estructura de la migración y el modelo.

Comment: Bueno, lo subo.

Comment: Gracias, por último, ¿podrías agregar el resultado de `dump($img);`?

Comment: Agrego eso en el index.blade?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás aplicando el método `groupBy()` en la colección, y dicho método lo que hace es agrupar por el campo que le indicas, y genera una nueva colección de colecciones/arreglos.

Según la documentación, genera algo así:

```
[
    'account-x10' => [
        ['account_id' => 'account-x10', 'product' => 'Chair'],
        ['account_id' => 'account-x10', 'product' => 'Bookcase'],
    ],
    'account-x11' => [
        ['account_id' => 'account-x11', 'product' => 'Desk'],
    ],
]
```

Lo más probable es que estás intentando acceder al campo file en una colección, y no en un objeto, por lo cual deberás iterar a través de la misma:

```
      @foreach ($img as $imgCollection)
        @foreach ($imgCollection as $post)
          <div class="tab-content">
              <div class="active tab-pane" id="activity">
                  <div class="post">
                      <div class="row mb-3">
                          <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
                              <a href="images/{{$post->file }}" class="fancybox" rel="ligthbox">
                                  <img src="images/{{$post->file }}" class="zoom img-fluid">
                              </a>
                          </div>                      
                      </div>

                      <div>
                        {{$post->description}}
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
        @endforeach
      @endforeach
```

La otra opción que tienes es hacer el groupBy en la consulta, y no en la colección como lo haces actualmente.

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias, una consulta mas, como hago el groupBy en la consulta?